# How to update property in an object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to update the value of a property in an object but I keep failing. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I'm trying to do a replace on each property of the **messages** property. How to do this with either javascript or Lodash? Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's my code:

```js
let arr = [{
  messages: {
    TEAM: "some <message> abc <1mn>",
    ITON: "acr <iconn> computer",
    LKON: "title <12mn> test"
  },
  messageId: '10',
  code: 'some code'
}]


arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.messages) {
    for (let key in obj.messages) {
      key = obj.messages[key].replace(/\</g, '&lt;');
    }
  }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the `.replace` call to the property of the object again:

```js
let arr = [{
     messages: {
    TEAM: "some <message> abc <1mn>",
    ITON: "acr <iconn> computer",
    LKON: "title <12mn> test"
 },
 messageId:'10',
 code: 'some code'
}]


arr.forEach(obj => {
    const { messages } = obj;
    if(messages) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.messages)) {
            messages[key] = value.replace(/\</g,'&lt;');
        }
    }
});

console.log(arr)
```